# Nenhuma conexão pode ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente. XAMPP

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Iae rapaziada, estou tendo problemas para fazer com que outras maquinas consigam se conectar a minha `localhost`, sendo que sempre ocorre o erro:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Nenhuma conex�o p�de ser
>   feita porque a m�quina de destino as recusou ativamente. in
>   C:\Users\Público\Desktop\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\www\conexao.php
>   on line 7

Este erro acontece apenas para outras maquinas, para mim a conexão funciona normalmente!

Arquivo PHP de conexão:

```
<?php
define('HOST', '127.0.0.1'); /*Se adicionado um ":1" no host, o erro ocorre para mim também*/
define('USUARIO', 'root');
define('SENHA', '[estou utilizando senha]');
define('DB', 'login');

$conexao = mysqli_connect(HOST, USUARIO, SENHA, DB) or die ('Não foi possivel conectar!');
mysqli_select_db($conexao, 'login') or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

É importânte resaltar que todo o código está sendo convertido para um arquivo Windows EXE através do PHP Desktop, visto que mesmo utilizando desde programa a conexão ocorre normalmente apenas para mim e o erro persiste para outras maquinas que tentam abrir o meu programa.

Meu firewall está desativado, apesar de existir exceções para as portas 3306 e 80.

Estou utilizando do XAMPP e com isso os módulos Apache e MySQL estão ativados normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(É importante que eu continue a utilizar o PHP Desktop, visto que não tenho conhecimento em outras formas de construir um arquivo executável para win.)

(Não tenho muito conhecimento com mysql)

Meu objetivo é descobrir o fonte do erro e poder conceder acesso a minha localhost para maquinas remotas.

Obrigado e desculpe por algumas informações desnecessárias.

Comment: Você precisa especificar o *IP* da rede local, abra o **Prompt de Comando** na maquina em que esta a rodar o *XAMPP* e digite **ipconfig** e veja a linha: **Endereço de IP / Endereço IPv4**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, funciona tudo certo na sua maquina, mas em outras maquinas não funciona e o mysql esta na sua máquina, é isso? Caso positivo o erro me parece ser causado por falta de permissão no mysql para acesso remoto. Tente o seguinte:

1 - Abra painel de controle do Xampp

2 - Clique no botão Shell, na tela que abrir digite:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

E tecle enter, informe a senha do root

3 - Voce agora está logado no console do mysql, agora insira o codigo abaixo e tecle enter para liberar o acesso root via rede local:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.0/255.255.255.0' IDENTIFIED BY 'SENHA-DO-ROOT-NOVAMENTE' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

No comando acima talvez voce tenha que alterar o endereço ip (192.168.0 no caso) para a faixa de ip da sua rede local

4 - Por ultimo rode o comando para efetivar

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

5 - Reiniciar o serviço do mysql

**--------- Edit**

Vendo agora o seu arquivo com mais atenção a configuração do host está para localhost, deste modo se você executar em outro pc o programa vai tentar acessar ele mesmo e não a sua máquina, você tem que informar o ip da rede local da sua maquina, abra o cmd e digite:

```
ipconfig
```

Saida esperada:

```
Configuração de IP do Windows


Adaptador Ethernet Ethernet:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::7830:4bd9:f3e0:b501%10
   Endereço IPv4. . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.2
   Máscara de Sub-rede . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Gateway Padrão. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1

Adaptador Ethernet Ethernet 2:

   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada
   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :

Adaptador Ethernet Ethernet 3:

   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada
   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
```

Procure por Endereço IPv4 (192.168.10.2 no meu caso) e insira esse endereço no lugar de 127.0.0.1

Comment: Sua resposta tem erro, o comando `ip config` não funcionara porque tem espaço.

Comment: Verdade, acabei digitando errado, já arrumei. Obrigado pelo aviso.

Comment: @rnd_rss Olá amigo, sua solução foi bem clara e resolveu este erro, valeu mesmo, agora vou atrás de resolver o outro erro que veio haha